# Changing image size depending on browser width

Tags: image-resizing, browser-width

I wanna add 10px to the width of an image proportionally to a change of 100px of the browser window width.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look up for a responsive css framework. Try using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for responsive layouts.
If you don't want to make a whole responsive layout try using media quesries. Get reference about css media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).